# Socket.io disconnects on http request

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I'm running nginx for my node.js application on a AWS EC2 instance. I want to use websockets (socket.io) and normal http request/response. My problem is, whenever I have an active socket connection from my mobile device to the server and try to make a normal http request, the mobile device's socket.io error function is called with the message "502 Bad Gateway".

Only socket works. Only normal http request works as well.

I figured out, that this problem occurred after I setup nginx to use https only.

Here is my nginx config in /sites-enabled /sites-available:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Nginx error log:

```
[error] 14117#14117: *50 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.94.9.226, server: example.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=rgXMQhL6mbSET8ktAAAA HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=rgXMQhL6mbSET8ktAAAA", host: "example.com"
```

iOS error log:

```
LOG SocketIOClient: Handling event: error with data: ["Got unknown error from server <html>\r\n<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"]
```

If you need any more information, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by myself. It was a really dumbass problem. I created a file inside my node.js server folder called access.log and told the morgan logger to write into the file. The thing I forgot was, that I'm using PM2 to restart the server whenever there is a change in code inside the server folder. So PM2 restarted the server every time I made a http request and the socket disconnected.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. I guess PM2 would take parameters to just watch changes to .js, .css and so? If so you should use that

Comment: I noticed that PM2 logs http request + stdout/stderr by itself, so I disabled morgan to write to a file. PM2 logs are sufficient for my needs.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Can you share the code or resource?

Answer (score 1):

Change your nginx config into two blocks

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

You want to only upgrade connection for `socket.io` and not other urls

Comment: Thank you for your help! I fixed the problem by myself.

Comment: Do share the solution as a answer

Comment: I did share the solution a few seconds ago